# Sql query for differnt rows as a one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which is giving me the following output:

```
AcctName                 budget 
Gross Salaries           232332
Basic Salaries           23123
Local Salaries           2312312
Local Travel             23424
country Travel           32242
Health care supplies     234234
Goods Supplies           3243242
```

You can see in this table I have three common names like `Salaries`, `Travel`, `Supplies` and their `budget`. I want query which can give me following result:

```
AcctNAme      Budget
Salaries       232323423
Travel         323232332
Supplies       232323232
```

The `budget` should be the sum of `salaries`, `travel` and `supplies`.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT T1.[AcctName], T0.[DebLTotal]
FROM (VALUES('Salaries'),('Travel'),('Supplies')) TT1(AcctName)
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
            WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies' END AS ActNAme,
       SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]) AS budget 
FROM OBGT T0 
   INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode] 
   INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId]
GROUP BY CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
              WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies' END) TT2 ON TT1.[AcctName] = TT2.[AcctName]
```

Comment: so as account name you want to remove all before the final blank anduse that as a group to sum? (if so....I hope you dont want something performant there.........string operations and group by lets just call that quite unperformant)      what did you try there so far?

Comment: no no i dont want to remove. it should be something like if it is like %Salaries% then salaries and so on. along with their sum of budget @Thomas

Comment: What did you try there so far?

Comment: i tried , could not find required result. thats why i posted here. if you know how to get that result in query. would be better. Thanks @Thomas

Comment: you should always also post code or queries you tried so that ppl see that you put effort into it and dont just try to let us do your job (which leads to minus votes and mostly no answers). also if an answer fits and solves a question always mark it as the answer that did it.

Comment: in your example you rever to it as giving the first table. don't think this is part of it then: "where T1.[AcctName] like '%Salarie%'"

Comment: @Kirat: try my code in answer below. Its short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional grouping like:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      AcctName VARCHAR(100) ,
      budget INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'Gross Salaries', 232332 ),
        ( 'Basic Salaries', 23123 ),
        ( 'Local Salaries', 2312312 ),
        ( 'Local Travel', 23424 ),
        ( 'country Travel', 32242 ),
        ( 'Health care supplies', 234234 ),
        ( 'Goods Supplies', 3243242 )

SELECT CASE WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
            WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
            WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies' 
            ELSE 'Other' END AS AcctNAme,
       SUM(budget) AS budget 
FROM @t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
              WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
              WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies' 
              ELSE 'Other' END
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT t.AcctNAme, l.budget
FROM (VALUES('Salaries'),('Travel'),('Supplies')) t(AcctNAme)
LEFT JOIN(
SELECT CASE WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
            WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
            WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies' END AS AcctNAme,
       SUM(budget) AS budget 
FROM @t
GROUP BY CASE WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
              WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
              WHEN AcctName LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies' END) l ON t.AcctNAme = l.AcctNAme
```

Comment: why do you not just use acctnAme in the group by? (shouldn't that work the same?)

Comment: @Thomas, no it won't work, because select is evaluated after grouping, so you can not use alias of select in grouping.

Comment: ah tnx. then I had an error in my version there (deleted it thus). Good point!

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri can you tell me if there is no data available for budget, e.g supplies has no budget then how can i use else part ?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri it is just changing the name of the acctNAme. if there is no budget for salaries then it should show like :  Salaries  -  Null means it should give me the acctName as such. Please check again

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i tried it with my orignal query which posted in the question . i am getting errors with that. can you check where the error is according to your edits. i dont know its giving me something syntax error. Please have a look on that

Comment: @Kirat, I have edited your question with corrected query

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Now i am getting : Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'AcctName'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "T1.AcctName" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "T0.DebLTotal" could not be bound.

Comment: @Kirat, may be just analyze your own query? You have `INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode] ` T1 is OACT and if it has no column AcctCode then why are you joining on that column? I can not answer you endless questions whole day

Comment: it has AcctCode . anyway thanks for help . . @GiorgiNakeuri

Answer (score 1):

This should work just fine.

```
select 'Salaries' as AcctName, (select sum(budget)
                                  from myTable
                                 where lower(AcctName) like '%salaries%') as Budget
union
select 'Travel', (select sum(budget)
                    from myTable
                   where lower(AcctName) like '%travel%')
union
select 'Supplies', (select sum(budget)
                      from myTable
                     where lower(AcctName) like '%supplies%')
```

You can **[test it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/91b71e/2)**

I use `lower()` to make a case-insensitive comparison. Many times this is not necessary, depending on how you defined your database [Collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You use `REVERSE` AND `RIGHT` function to reverse `ActName`

Example:

```
SELECT RIGHT(S, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(S)))FROM(
SELECT 'Health care supplies' AS S) AS A

-- Result

supplies
```

You can try this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
   SUM(Budget) OVER(PARTITION BY AcctName) AS Budget
FROM (
   SELECT
      RIGHT(AcctName, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(AcctName))) AS AcctName,
      Budget
   FROM Your_Table) AS A
```

Comment: @Kirat This is getting the last word, which means it will fail for `'Travel expenses'` for example (but this might not be a problem, depending on your data model is organized). Also, the select statement should be `SELECT DISTINCT AcctName, SUM...` instead.